# How to change object keys in deeply nested object with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a following kind of object:

```
{
  options: [
    { id: 1, value: 'a' }
  ],
  nestedObj: {
    options: [
      { id: 2, value: 'b' }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I change the key 'id' on both, options array in first level and in the nested level? I have tried to use lodash for this but not have been able to get the desired result:

```
{
  options: [
    { newKey: 1, value: 'a'
  ],
  nestedObj: {
    options: [
      { newKey: 2, value: 'b' }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I would like to find a function which works like [lodash mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys) but would iterate through deep nested object.

Comment: Can it appear at any depth?

Comment: @alex yes, the options array with objects with those key value pairs can and will appear at any depth.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs#transform) recursively to replace keys:

```js
var obj = {
  options: [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'a'
  }],
  nestedObj: {
    options: [{
      id: 2,
      value: 'b'
    }]
  }
};

console.log(replaceKeysDeep(obj, {
  id: 'newKey',
  options: 'items'
}));

function replaceKeysDeep(obj, keysMap) { // keysMap = { oldKey1: newKey1, oldKey2: newKey2, etc...
  return _.transform(obj, function(result, value, key) { // transform to a new object

    var currentKey = keysMap[key] || key; // if the key is in keysMap use the replacement, if not use the original key

    result[currentKey] = _.isObject(value) ? replaceKeysDeep(value, keysMap) : value; // if the key is an object run it through the inner function - replaceKeys
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: This fails with circular objects :/